# Delete all contacts in Marketing Cloud to delete all duplicates

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, data-synchronization, bulk-delete

We have duplicates in our all contacts in Marketing Cloud. To solve this, we want to delete all contacts (audience builder).

We use the Marketing Cloud connector, and send emails to synchronized data extensions. Because of this connector the all contacts will be filled with fresh data after 15 minutes right?

Is there any reason not to do this? What can go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting all your contacts because you have some duplicates seems a little brash. This would delete all tracking data associated and unsub/held status. I would recommend using the following article to help identify the contacts you want to delete, and simply delete those: '[Permanently remove Contacts or Subscribers and associated data from Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313920&type=1&mode=1)'

If you are deleting sync contacts, you would need to pause the sync during the entire time the contact deletion is occuring, so you don't sync contacts you are actively trying to delete. I would also suggest removing any unneeded sendable DE to speed up the delete process.